# Creating Mesh from Point Cloud

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, .obj

I'm looking for a way to create a mesh `.obj` file from point cloud for an academic research project. I'm flexible about the algorithm and its runtime and space complexity.

After searching for a while I couldn't find out and 3-party library that could do this.

Answer (score 2):

## ARKit 4.0

In ARKit 3.5 and ARKit 4.0 you can create a mesh from dense point cloud using LiDAR scanner and `Scene Reconstruction` option. Also, in ARKit 4.0 you can find Depth API.

## ARKit 3.0

There's no way in ARKit 3.0 to create a mesh from Point Cloud at the moment. You can do it in third party solutions like [Abound SDK](https://www.aboundlabs.com). There are four simple steps to save and access maps for a photogrammetry: create the delegate, implement saving and just run your app for viewing the map.

> After your spatial map will be uploaded, the data's quickly processed and then made available. A convenient way to access the data is via the web dashboard:

- Open the dashboard scans view at dashboard.aboundlabs.com/scans.
- Scans made from your apps will appear as thumbnail images with your
  latest scans listed first. To view the 3D scan, click on the image.
- **To download the 3D textured mesh in zipped `obj` format click on ⤓ icon**.

Here's how `AboundScanController` class looks like:

[image]

Comment: This library looks great but I'm already using ARKit and only need the ability to convert .ply files to .obj files on device

Comment: Hi Nativ, how you did that? I’m really interesed on create the mesh from the ply and export obj or stl